# Is there a way to run geofence when app is closed?

Tags: android, geofencing, android-geofence

I am currently working on a project and I was wondering if there was way to run Geo-fence when android app is closed?

Answer (score 0):

If you follow all the instructions here https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing, your app should be able to run in the background. One thing to keep in mind is this;

```
  .setExpirationDuration(Constants.GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_MILLISECONDS)
```

Depending on your implementation, you can specify how long geofences will stay in your Location Services. Also a reboot will clear all geofences.